# Grouping output edges from graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to draw a graph with two kinds of edges, and I want the two kinds of edges to link to each node from opposite sides, as much as possible.  I.e. if an edge of type A enters from the left, I want all edges of type B to exit to the right.  I know I could specify compass directions, but I'd like graphviz to be able to switch this around to minimize graph clutter.

Is it this, or something similar, possible?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to specify compass points, you'll probably not want to use [HTML like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) and [ports](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos) either.

If you're using dot, you still can achieve something similar by using the `samehead` and the `sametail` attributes. From the reference:

> Edges with the same head and the same
>   samehead value are aimed at the same
>   point on the head

This lets you group outgoing and incoming edges. Here's a simple example:

```
digraph g{
    rankdir=LR;
    edge[samehead=h1, sametail=t1];
    a1->b->c1;
    a2->b->c2;
    edge[samehead=h2, sametail=t2];
    a3->b->c3;
    a4->b->c4;
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

This of course is only about grouping heads and tails of edges, and does not guarantee opposite sides for edges of different types.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, but it still doesn't do what I want.  I'll see if I can make a more detailed explanation of what I want to achieve, perhaps on a separate web page.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to replace my old nodes with edges, thus creating two nodes - one for each "port" in the graph.  I can then my edges between these "port nodes".  Eg. instead of

```
node1 -> node2 [ sametail="b", samehead = "a" ]
```

I write

```
node1_a -> node1_b [ dir=none, style=bold ]
node2_a -> node2_b [ dir=none, style=bold ]

node1_a -> node2_b // if I got head and tail right :-)
```

Although I don't get boxes for my "nodes", this works okay for my purposes.